# Filtering out null values only if they exist in SQL select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below I have sql select to retrieve values from a table. I want to retrieve the values from tableA regardless of whether or not there are matching rows in tableB. The below gives me both non-null values and null values. How do I filter out the null values if non-null rows exist, but otherwise keep the null values?

```
SELECT a.* FROM
(
    SELECT
            id,
            col1, 
            coll2
        FROM tableA a LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b ON b.col1=a.col1 and b.col2='value'
        WHERE a.id= @id
          AND a.col2= @arg

) AS a

 ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

Comment: You're missing a code segment. ) is missing it's friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by counting the number of matches using a window function.  Then, either return all rows in `A` if there are no matching `B` rows, or only return the rows that do match:

```
select id, col1, col2
from (SELECT a.id, a.col1, a.coll2,
             count(b.id) over () as numbs
      FROM tableA a LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b ON b.col1=a.col1 and b.col2='value'
      WHERE a.id = @id AND a.col2= @arg
     ) ab
where numbs = 0 or b.id is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter them out in WHERE clause

```
SELECT
    id,
    col1, 
    coll2
FROM tableA a LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b ON b.col1=a.col1 and b.col2='value'
WHERE a.id= @id
  AND a.col2= @arg
  AND A.Col1 IS NOT NULL -- HERE
) AS a

ORDER BY col1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, people write code like Marko that puts a filter (b.col2 = 'value') in the JOIN clause.  While this works, it is not good practice.

Also, you should get in the habit of having the ON clause in the right sequence.  We are joining table A to table B, why write it as B.col1 = A.col1 which is backwards.

While the above statement works, it could definitely be improved.

I created the following test tables.

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb;
go

-- Table A
if object_id('A') > 0 drop table A
go
create table A
(
  id1 int,
  col1 int,
  col2 varchar(16)
);
go

-- Add data
insert into A
values
(1, 1, 'Good data'),
(2, 2, 'Good data'),
(3, 3, 'Good data');

-- Table B
if object_id('B') > 0 drop table B
go
create table B
(
  id1 int,
  col1 int,
  col2 varchar(16)
);

-- Add data
insert into B
values
(1, 1, 'Good data'),
(2, 2, 'Good data'),
(3, NULL, 'Null data');
```

Here is the improved statement.  I choose literals instead of variables.  However, you can change for your example.

```
-- Filter non matching records
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON 
    A.col1 = B.col1 
WHERE 
    B.col1 IS NOT NULL AND
    A.id1 in (1, 2) AND
    A.col2 = 'Good data'
ORDER BY
    A.id1 DESC
```

Here is an image of the output.

[image]